# If every block in graph G is eulerian, is G necessarily eulerian?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that if $G$ is Eulerian, then every block contained within it is also Eulerian, but is the converse true?

Comment: Is G connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every block is Eulerian, then every vertex in $G$ which is the edge-disjoint union of its blocks has even degree. This holds for connected graphs $G$.